# setTextAlignment() & setGravity() is not working dynamically

Tags: android, android-edittext, text-alignment

Note : It is not a duplicate question, looking for suggest.

I have a **EditText**, where the **EditText** should have to align its text based on user request **on click** of Right Alignment button, Center Alignment Button & Left Alignment Button.

When I click on the alignment button, It is not getting effected to **EditText**.

i have used setTextAlignment() &  setGravity(). both are not working in my scenario.

[image]

XML

```
<LinearLayout
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@id/spacing_container"
            android:layout_below="@id/cont"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
            android:padding="10dp">

            <EditText
                android:text="HINT"
                android:id="@+id/text_input_ID"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="30sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Alignment Container XML

```
<LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/text_alignment_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:baselineAligned="false"
                android:gravity="center"
                orientation="horizontal"
                android:visibility="gone">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/text_align_left_ID"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/align_left"
                        android:src="@drawable/align_left" />

                    <ImageView
                       android:id="@+id/text_align_center_ID"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/align_center"
                        android:src="@drawable/align_center" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/text_align_right_ID"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/align_right"
                        android:src="@drawable/align_right" />
            </LinearLayout>
```

onClickListerner

```
switch(v.getId){

    case R.id.text_align_left_ID :
          text_input.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_TEXT_START);
          break;
    case R.id.text_align_center_ID :
          text_input.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
          break;
    case R.id.text_align_right_ID :
          text_input.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_TEXT_END);
          break;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
switch(v.getId){
    case R.id.text_align_left_ID :
          text_input.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
          break;
    case R.id.text_align_center_ID :
          text_input.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
          break;
    case R.id.text_align_right_ID :
          text_input.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
          break;
}
```

Comment: so do you want to set gravity of hint?

Comment: In my case : text_input.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
                text_input.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);   it is working fine

Comment: Everything is working fine (even for left &amp; right). But, i have used both setGravity() and setTextAlignment().

Thanks for your hint to achieve the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

you should try this

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.START;
text_input.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. this solution makes the Edittext to setGravity() but, not the text "HINT". I mean, when the text inside the edittext is higher characters [let the characters are  greater than 20 in edittext ] the gravity is applicable for edittext and text inside edittext